# Batch, Can I open a url from a batch script?

Tags: file, batch-file, search

I'll show you what I have then try to explain the question,

```
@echo off

Echo put search in front of a question to search for the answer on the internet

Set /p question=
```

That's it so far, if the user puts search I front of a question it searches the Internet, I would like it so it is in one batch file as well. Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you search the Internet with a batch script and a keyword?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30135897/how-do-you-search-the-internet-with-a-batch-script-and-a-keyword)

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to open the default web browser, it's as simple as using `start`.

This snippet will check to see if your question variable contains "search:" by replacing "search:" and comparing against the original. If they match, search wasn't entered.

```
@setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion

set /p question=
set questionWOspaces=%question: =+%
IF NOT "%question:search:=%"=="%question%" (START http://www.google.com/search?q="%questionWOspaces:search:=%")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
cd C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer
iexplore http://www.google.pt/search?q=%search%+site:https://stackoverflow.com/
```

or simple

```
START "" "http://www.google.com/search?q=%*"
```

Also look at this **[POST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20782734/open-a-url-without-using-a-browser-from-a-batch-file)** & this [**POST**](https://superuser.com/questions/25538/how-to-download-files-from-command-line-in-windows-like-wget-is-doing)

help full links

[Batch File Commands](http://academic.evergreen.edu/projects/biophysics/technotes/program/batch.htm)

[Start a program, command or batch script (opens in a new window.)](http://ss64.com/nt/start.html)